# How Does ServiceProcess.ServiceController Do Its Work?

Tags: c#, .net, service, windows-services

**The Setup:**

We have two Servers. They are on different subnets, but can still communicate with each other.

**The Issue:**

Server 1 used to query Server 2's Services with a `ServiceController.Status` call successfully, until our IT Staff tightened the firewall between the two subnets (we lost RDP access to Server 2 and `ServiceController.Status` calls from Server 1 to Server 2 started to fail).

IT has relaxed the firewall a bit (so RDP to Server 2 now works), but our `ServiceController.Status` calls still fail (The error is: *Cannot open Service Control Manager on Computer*).

**The Question:**

How does `ServiceProcess.ServiceController` perform it's tasks? Does it use a special TCP Port when doing it's work?

I am suspecting that the firewall is preventing remote access to the Service Controller on Server 2, so I'd like to tell our IT staff what ports we need opened.

I've looked at [the MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.aspx), but I haven't been able to find out what I need.

Comment: Are you sure it's RDP, and not RPC? RDP is the Remote Desktop Protocol, used for terminal services i.e. Windows Remote Desktop. RPC is Remote Procedure Call, used for inter-process communication. RPC works a variety of ways depending on what modes of communication are available between the two processes (which in turn depends on how much metal separates the two processes).

Comment: @KeithS: Yeah, I did mean RDP. We lost Remote Desktop access at the same time our ServiceController calls started to fail.

Comment: OK, well, ServiceController does not use RDP for its function, so you're barking up the wrong tree getting RDP working and thinking that'll solve your ServiceController call problems. Have a look at my answer and make sure the IT guys provide access to at least one of the ports listed for each protocol and service category.

Comment: @KeithS: Yeah, but I figured the root cause might be the same (a Firewall that is too strict). That's why I want to see how our calls function.

Comment: @Onion-Knight -- did you figure out which specific port is needed for ServiceController.Status? I have the exact same question. While the article that KeithS linked to lists several ports, I am hoping there is just one specific port needed for this narrow requirement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out this TechNet article: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738291(v=ws.10).aspx#w2k3tr_rpc_how_vfae. It contains a table of the protocols and their associated socket ports that can be used by RPC, which the .NET ServiceController class depends on. Your IT staff probably, in their exuberance, closed one or more of these ports (some are more vital than others, depending on how many other options are available), rendering RPC inoperable.